# How to include element on multipe websites without inheriting their styling?

Tags: css

I want to include `select` with my styling on many websites, but a lot of them have styled their `select` elements (without any classes) heavily.

How my `select` can be included without inheriting all the styles that particular website used?

According to snippet below, I expect that `my_select` would not have `select` styling applied.

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
 /* 50x more rules that i dont want to overwrite one by one */
}
```

```html
<!-- Their select -->
<select>
    <option value="">Their select</option>
</select>

<!-- Mine select -->
<select class="my_select" id="my_select">
    <option value="">My select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: use an inline style with !important
<select style="border:solid 1px red !important">...

Comment: @MattBunch But external site styles will still be applied to my select, and I cannot predict what kind of styling particular website will use.

Comment: you will need to cover the majority of the default attributes of the select.
Another way, would be not use a select, but make your own select dropdown with css and javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for. If you set all attributes to the initial value, then you will be able to write your custom styles from a clean slate. This might cause some unintended consequences however since the initial values might not be exactly what you expect.

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
 /* 50x more rules that i dont want to overwrite one by one */
}

.my_select {
    all: initial;
    /* Set all of your own styles here */
}
```

```html
<!-- Their select -->
<select>
    <option value="">Their select</option>
</select>

<!-- Mine select -->
<select class="my_select" id="my_select">
    <option value="">My select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That's closest so far, but why `#my_select` do not look like default HTML select anymore and how could I make it look like that?

Comment: That's what I meant by the unintended consequences. This resets every single attribute, including the styling that the browser would normally put on a select element. At some point you will have to write your own css to get it look how you want.

Comment: I see. The solution for this is using `all: revert`, however now it is only supported by Safari. Maybe some day... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert

Answer (score 0):

Give your select a unique ID that the external site is unlikely to be using:

```
ul#somethingsomething { styles.... }
```

Comment: This will not work. All their CSS rules will still be applied if they do not use any classes or ids for styling their select elements.

Comment: No, this CSS is more specific than tags without IDs or classes.

See: http://cssspecificity.com/

Comment: I think my question may not be clear enough. I added code snippet as an example. According to what you say adding a unique ID would solve my problem. I made a snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/5kv8m7nr/2/ I would expect that `appearance` rule would not apply to `#my_select` element then, but it still does.

Comment: Your CSS does not override the `appearance` attribute, so it will be inherited from what's already there.

Comment: Correct, and I want to override everything without specifing exact classes. Look on Logiwan992 answer.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you simply cannot do this, CSS is all about specificity, if you only reference an element tag, but the site you want this on has that same element tag + a `class`, you will get the styles, thats it, you either have to be more specific with your CSS (using `id`, `class`, etc, or in the worst case `!important`) or set everything up with JavaScript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity